# Blocking DC power to active GPS antenna

Tags: capacitor, rf, antenna, gps, split

I would like to connect two GPS receivers to a single active antenna letting the DC voltage form only one receiver to reach the antenna. In [this blog post](https://rtklibexplorer.wordpress.com/2017/04/07/zero-baseline-experiment/) the guy made his own RF part by putting a capacitor into a male to male SMA adapter which is a very low-cost solution. I wonder whether there are similarly working low-cost parts readily available off the shelf so that I do not have to build it myself. The cheapest GPS antenna splitter I could find is a [Tallysman TW150](https://www.navtechgps.com/departments/equipment/rf_networking/splitters/tw150_l_band/gnss_1_to_2_signal_splitter/?F_Sort=4) for $85 while the solution with a custom capacitor must cost much less.

Answer (score 1):

The component that you want is called a "DC block". You could also get a "bias tee" and leave the bias connection disconnected. Don't forget that you will also need an RF power divider that works at the frequencies you're trying to receive, and please note that not all power dividers will pass through DC. If you get one that doesn't, then you'll need to add the DC back in with a bias tee.